# How to repaint a wall with peeling paint

Tags: painting, paint-removal

I have a wall that needs repainting:

[image]

I guess I first need to remove the existing paint and then repaint?

How do I remove the paint? With a heat gun or some chemical way?

Also, I prefer not to repaint the whole thing but only one wall:

[image]

Is that a good idea? If yes, how do I remove the paint only from one wall and not from the other walls and ceiling?

Thanks
Jenia

Answer (score 2):

You only need to remove loose or peeling paint - you can paint over paint that is in good condition. Mechanical means (sanding or scraping) are typically sufficient to remove paint that needs to be removed.

In painting a single wall, you will likely have problems matching the color of the other walls. You'll be amazed just how many shades of "white" there are, and how glaring the difference can be. Depending on the use of the area this may not be a concern.

But, if you have water damage, you need to first solve the leak (source of water), and you may need to replace some drywall as well as (before) the painting to fully resolve the damage.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I have one question now: - What do I do with regards to the line between where the paint is peeled/scraped and where the paint remains? Can I apply joint-compound to smooth that off?

Comment: Typically you would feather the edge with sandpaper in cases where it's a large difference in height. The wall in your photo could use washing prior to painting as well; the canonical answer there is Tri-Sodium Phosphate (TSP) which is available in hardware stores.

Comment: @Excnerwal, in the first picture you see, is it the drywall that is peeling or the paint? See the brown paper there? That looks like the drywall.